# Java better way to store values from matrix of int by specific values

Tags: java, matrix

I have an matrix of int[][] and I want to store coords in different arrays according to it's values in the matrix.
I think that my solution works but it's not very performant...

```
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Coords>> storeValues(int[][] labels) {
    int max = getMaxValue(labels);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Coords>> collection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Coords>>();
    ArrayList<Coords> coords;

    while (max > 0) {
        coords = new ArrayList<Coords>();
        for (int x = 0; x < labels.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < labels[0].length; y++) {
                if (max == labels[x][y]) {
                    coords.add(new Coords(x,y));
                }
            }
        }
        collection.add(coords);
        --max;
    }
    return collection;
}

private int getMaxValue(int[][] labels) {
    int max = labels[0][0];
    for (int tabValue[] : labels) {
        for (int value : tabValue) {
            if (max < value) {
                max = value;
            }
        }

    }
    return max;
}
```

For exemple :
My matrix containt

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0 ],  
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],  
  [ 1, 2, 2 ],   
  [ 2, 2, 5 ] ]
```

Expected result

```
ArrayList{ 
  ArrayList{ Coord[0,0], Coord[1,0], Coord[2,0] }, // list of 0 value  
  ArrayList{ Coord[0,1], Coord[1,1], Coord[2,1], Coord[0,3] }, // list of 1 value
  ...
}
```

Comment: I could not understand your purpose. How can this matrix convert into such two lists? What are your constraints?

Comment: what is your actual question? are you looking for a different algorithm? debugging your existing algorithm?

Comment: Are the values always *sorted* in the matrix?

Comment: My values are grouped but not especially sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the values are already sorted, the solution is rather simple: Just walk through the matrix (in the sorted order), and always create a new list when you encounter a new value.

When the values are **not** sorted, then you can create a list of coordinates, sort these by the corresponding value, and then apply the same method to it like for the sorted case.

Both versions are implemented here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortMatrixCoordinates
{
    static class Coords
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        Coords(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "("+x+","+y+")";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        runWithSortedMatrix();
        runWithUnsortedMatrix();
    }

    private static void runWithSortedMatrix()
    {
        int labels[][] = new int[][]{
            { 0, 0, 0 },  
            { 1, 1, 1 },  
            { 1, 2, 2 },   
            { 2, 2, 5 } };

        System.out.println("Result with sorted matrix:");
        List<List<Coords>> result = storeValues(labels);
        for (List<Coords> list : result)
        {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }

    private static void runWithUnsortedMatrix()
    {
        int labels[][] = new int[][]{
            { 0, 0, 0 },  
            { 3, 3, 3 },  
            { 3, 2, 2 },   
            { 2, 2, 1 } };

        System.out.println("Result with unsorted matrix:");
        List<List<Coords>> result = storeValuesSorting(labels);
        for (List<Coords> list : result)
        {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }

    public static List<List<Coords>> storeValues(final int[][] labels)
    {
        List<List<Coords>> result = new ArrayList<List<Coords>>();
        List<Coords> coords = null;
        int previousValue = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < labels.length; x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < labels[0].length; y++) 
            {
                int value = labels[x][y];
                if ((x == 0 && y == 0) || previousValue != value)
                {
                    coords = new ArrayList<Coords>();
                    result.add(coords);
                }
                coords.add(new Coords(x,y));
                previousValue = value;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static List<List<Coords>> storeValuesSorting(final int[][] labels) 
    {
      List<Coords> sortedCoords = new ArrayList<Coords>();
      for (int x = 0; x < labels.length; x++) 
      {
          for (int y = 0; y < labels[0].length; y++) 
          {
              sortedCoords.add(new Coords(x,y));
          }
      }
      Collections.sort(sortedCoords, new Comparator<Coords>()
      {
          @Override
          public int compare(Coords c0, Coords c1)
          {
              int v0 = labels[c0.x][c0.y];
              int v1 = labels[c1.x][c1.y];
              return Integer.compare(v0, v1);
          }

      });
      List<List<Coords>> result = new ArrayList<List<Coords>>();
      List<Coords> coords = null;
      int previousValue = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<sortedCoords.size(); i++) 
      {
          Coords c = sortedCoords.get(i);          
          int value = labels[c.x][c.y];
          if (i == 0 || previousValue != value)
          {
              coords = new ArrayList<Coords>();
              result.add(coords);
          }
          coords.add(c);
          previousValue = value;
      }
      return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution!

Comment: @melkir OK, I already assumed that they are grouped (if they were *not* grouped, you could use a solution like that proposed by @mfrankli ). So they are not sorted - then the question is still whether the *output* should be sorted according to the value. But this can be achieved with either my solution or that of mfrankli, when you use a `TreeSet` instead of a `HashMap` there.

Comment: @mfrankli It's rather simple, but as pointed out above: It makes the assumption that the values are *grouped*. While this seems to be the case here, your solution does *not* make this assumption, and thus, would be applicable for similar (but more general) tasks. Also, the "optional sorting stuff" that I mentioned in the comment to your answer can be considered as a neat additional feature of your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your goal should be to iterate as little as possible. You can actually do it in one single (nested) iteration, if you use a Map for building up your desired data structure. Most helpful here is a `TreeMap`, because it automatically sorts by key..

The logic is, instead of nested lists, build up a `new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Coords>>`. 
The Integer-key is your value, and the arrayList is the list of Coords for that value.

You iterate over the matrix as before, but without calculation of `max`. This saves you the whole `getMaxValue` method and the outer while loop.
For each value, you first check if the `TreeMap` has an entry with that key. If yes, add your new `Coord` to map.get(val). If no, create a `new ArrayList<Coord>`, add your `Coord` to that list, and put it into the map.

If you absolutely must have ArrayList> as return type, you can simply convert the map's valueSet at the end with `return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Coord>>(map.values())`

Comment: Thank's ! I had try to use TreeMap, but without sucess.. with your logic it should work now :)

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that your current algorithm might not perform well. If you say your matrix has dimension `M*N`, a runtime analysis might look like:

```
max_val = get_max_val(); // O(M*N)
for i from max_val to 0: // O(max_val)
    // O(M*N)
    for x from 0 to M:
        for y from 0 to N:
            do_stuff;
```

In other words, this works out to `O(M*N*max_val)`. This is dangerous if your `max_val` is very large; especially since the actual algorithm doesn't *have* to depend on *what* the values are (just which ones are the same).

An alternative algorithm which only depends on `M` and `N`:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Coords>> coordsMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Coords>>();
for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < labels[i].length; j++) {
        if (coordsMap.containsKey(labels[i][j])) {
            ArrayList<Coords> coords = coordsMap.get(labels[i][j]);
            coordsMap.put(labels[i][j], coords.add(new Coords(i, j));
        }
    }
}

// collect results
ArrayList<ArrayList<Coords>> coordsList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Coords>>();
for (Integer label : coordsMap.keySet()) {
    coordsList.add(coordsMap.get(label));
}
return coordsList;
```

The runtime on this is `M*N*(HashMap get/put time)`.

If you want to have an ArrayList for every value `from 0 to max_val`, where an absence of coordinates with that label is represented by an empty ArrayList, you could change the `// collect results` portion to look something like:

```
// collect results
for (int i = 0; i < max_val; i++) {
    if (coordsMap.containsKey(i)) {
        coordsList.add(coordsMap.get(i));
    }
    else {
        coordsList.add(new ArrayList<Coords>());
    }
}
```

As Marco13's comment on your question suggests, the actual performance will likely depend somewhat on how your data actually looks.

Comment: When using a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`, then the order would be the same as the order in which the values are encountered in the matrix. And when using a `TreeMap<Integer, ...>` instead of a `HashMap<...>`, the output would also be sorted. However, +1

Comment: @mfrankli Is it better to store values in order with TreeMap or sort them after and use your solution ?

Comment: As they say, "premature optimization is the root of all evil". In other words - the difference is probably marginal. Careful analysis might show a small difference, but algorithmically it's pretty similar.